# OpenERP 7: Rmove number after salesman name at sales analysis reporting page

Tags: odoo

[image: sale analysis image]

I want remove (26)(2)(45)... etc,but can't find solutions

Answer (score 0):

Add this to in your xml file.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_order_product_tree_inherited">
    <field name="name">sale.report.tree.inherited</field>
    <field name="model">sale.report</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_product_tree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <xpath expr="//field[@name='nbr']" position="replace">
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

It will remove the # of line from the sale analysis report.

Comment: I don‘t want to remove # of line ,I had get answer from https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-7-how-to-remove-count-number-after-salesman-name-at-sales-analysis-reporting-page-61424